# Debug Console: Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install... F

Tags: android, flutter, macos, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run app on Android Emulator and it's saying that **INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]** but when I wipe data from AVD and restart VS Code and try again, sam error.. Sometimes I go `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and sometimes work but sometimes don't. I tried to do every solution that people posted previously in their similar problems but solutions don't work. When I use Windows10 on my PC I am not having this problem but on my Mackbook Air 2020 I am facing this on all projects. P.S This is new project(blank template).

````
flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 arm64. If you
notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering
with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             12.9s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...                689ms
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install
/Users/harunbegic/Desktop/dev/flutter/login_authh/build/app/outp
uts/flutter-apk/app.apk: Failure
[INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64. ```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found the solution:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Virtual Device Manager
3. Find your emulator and go Edit(Virtual Device Configuration)
4. Show Advanced Settings
5. Scroll down and find Interal Storage(for me it was by default 800MB)
6. Set how many MB you want to emulator have ( I putted 6000MB and it works fine)

Hope it helps!

P.S It may take some time to emulator reloads after changes! Be patient :D

Comment: This worked for me, but NOT when I tried 3000MB.  Only when I tried 6000MB!  Also, special note: to find "Edit" as mentioned above, I had to fly my mouse over a little pencil icon in Android Studio Device Manager, to see that it said "edit" on it.  Meanwhile, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As the error says [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]. You have to increase the storage of the device.

To do that,

1. go to device manager
2. click edit device
3. click show advanced manager
4. find internal storage and increase it to 1000 - 3000MB or until it won't show an error.

Done~